# The difference between 'TALK' and 'SAY'

Tags: word-usage

Q: Tell me about an uncomfortable situation you've had with a product.

A: I have been using iPhone 6 for about 6 months but I haven't had any uncomfortable situation with my phone. So,

> 1. I really don't have anything to talk about.

I'm perfectly comfortable saying like #1, but what about #2?

> 2. I really don't have anything to talk about an uncomfortable situation I've had with my phone.

I think the preposition 'about' already has it's object 'anything', so I think it is not right. but how about #3?

> 3.I really don't have anything to say about an uncomfortable situation I've had with my phone.

Since 'anything' is the object of the verb 'say', I feel we can add ***about an uncomfortable situation I've had with my phone.***

So, I think #1,3 are possible to use and grammatically correct. Am I right to think this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference between **talk** and **say** is that *to talk* is to "to speak about, to converse" and *to say* is "to state something, to affirm or deny something".

I was talking with customer service about my new phone's bad sound quality.
--What did the customer service rep say? Did he give you a new phone?

I find your #2 ungrammatical.

Comment: I think the key difference here is that *talk* is an intransitive verb, while *say* is transitive (its direct object should be the words spoken).

Answer (score 0):

In your case 'say' sounds much better.

> So I really don't have anything to say

Here you don't need to repeat yourself by adding *"...about an uncomfortable situation I've had with my phone"* again, since you already mentioned it in your first sentence that you haven't had any problems with the phone.

Also you can say the whole thing like this:

> I have been using iPhone 6 for about 6 months but I haven't had any
>   problems with it yet.

It is more precise and less confusing.

---

***Regarding the difference between ['say' and 'talk'](http://staff.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/tellsay.html):***

> ***Say***: *Say* is most often used without a *personal object*. If we want to put a personal object after say, we use **to**.
>
> ***example:*** She said that it was my last chance.

and,

> ***Talk:*** *Talk* is the more usual word to refer to conversational exchanges and informal communication.
>
> ***example:*** When she walked into the room everybody stopped talking.

Answer (score 0):

"SAY" is a 'one-way' process, and "TALK" presumes there are at least two interlocutors (unless you are talking to yourself...)
Therefore, we say "I have nothing to say about this situation" or "There's nothing to talk about"