# There is nothing to talk about + noun

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

There is a [question on French SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22510/translation-of-there-is-nothing-to-talk-about) asking for a translation of **There is nothing to talk about**.

Multiple answers give a translation for **There is nothing to talk about** followed by a noun, for example **There is nothing to talk about this book**.

I find these constructions ungrammatical and [this QA (The difference between 'TALK' and 'SAY')](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64384/the-difference-between-talk-and-say/64956#64956) seems to confirm.

I would like to confirm that I am not the one making a mistake. Is **There is nothing to talk about + noun** grammatically incorrect and better replaced by **There is nothing to say about + noun**?

Comment: You're correct, obviously. But that's hardly surprising, since French SE  isn't really the kind of site where you could reasonably expect everything to be written in impeccable English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

The constructions employed by the two verbs are different:

- > He says UTTERANCE about TOPIC. ...

  The verb *SAY* is transitive and takes a direct object. In the construction *There is nothing to say about TOPIC*, *nothing* represents that direct object—the UTTERANCE. There is a syntactic slot left for another noun: object of the preposition *about*, representing the TOPIC.
- > He talks about TOPIC. ...

  The verb *TALK* is intransitive and does not take an object. In the construction *There is nothing to talk about*, *nothing* represents the object of the preposition *about*—the TOPIC. There is no syntactic slot left for another noun to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Sample sentences make it easier, without a long explanation using formal grammar:

There is nothing to talk about in this regard.

OR
I have nothing (left) to talk about in this regard.
/with regard to, as regards, with respect to some x//in this regard/with respect to this, etc./ can be used to make the sentence work.

There is nothing (else) to be said about this book.
I have nothing to say about this book.

This is not correct English: **There is nothing to talk about this book**. (It is a literal translation from of the French)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Incorrect: "There is nothing left to talk about David."

Correct: "There is nothing left to say about David."

Correct: "There is nothing left to talk about."

Reason: "Talk" is an intransitive verb, as mentioned in other posts, and cannot be applied to a direct object.

Comment: Example may be confusing, became "There is nothing left to talk about, David." is perfectly valid, and a common turn of phrase when talking to that jerk Dave.

Comment: Good point. The comma is a key element; "That's enough peter" is, for example, very different from "That's enough, Peter."